# JavaScript "copy" HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html, addition

I am making a quiz website and at the edit screen of a {id} quiz can I edit + add questions (and answers)

Now I have a form, which I want to "copy" using JavaScript so it gets dynamic, ofcourse the Question number should be 2, 3, 4 and so forth after clicking on "Add Question"

This is what I had before, but I think there is a more efficient way to sort of copy the form instead of making a complete new one.

But I'm kind off stuck with how to do it..

HTML

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'quizzes/edit', 'id' => 'quiz')) }}
{{ Form::button('Add Question', array('onclick' => 'addQuestion()', 'id' => 'questionadd', 'value' => 'Add new question')) }}
{{ Form::submit('Edit Quiz', array('id' => 'quizsubmit')) }}

    <p id="questiontitle">Question 1</p>
    {{ Form::text('', null, array('placeholder' => 'Question 1', 'size' => '40', 'id' => 'questions', 'onfocus' => 'showAnswers(this)')) }} <br>
    {{ Form::text('', null, array('placeholder' => 'Good Answer', 'size' => '30', 'id' => 'answers')) }}
    {{ Form::text('', null, array('placeholder' => 'False Answer', 'size' => '30', 'id' => 'answers')) }}
    {{ Form::text('', null, array('placeholder' => 'False Answer', 'size' => '30', 'id' => 'answers')) }}


{{ Form::close() }}
```

JavaScript

```
var qlimit = 10; // Max questions
var qcount = 1; // There are 4 questions already

function addQuestion()
{
// Get the quiz form element
var quiz = document.getElementById('quiz');

// Good to do error checking, make sure we managed to get something
if (quiz) {
    if (qcount < qlimit) {
        // Create a new <p> element
        var newQ = document.createElement('p');
        newQ.innerHTML = 'Question ' + (qcount + 1);

        // Create the new text box
        var newInput = document.createElement('input');
        newInput.type = 'text';
        newInput.name = 'questions[]'

        var newQ = document.createElement('p');
        newQ.innerHTML = 'Question ' + (qcount + 1);

        // Error checking
        if (newInput && newQ) {
            // Add the new elements to the form
            quiz.appendChild(newQ);
            quiz.appendChild(newInput);


            // Increment the count
            qcount++;
        }
    }

    // Error message when maximum amount of questions is reached
    else {
        alert('The maximum amount of questions is ' + qcount);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var quizForm = document.getElementByID('quiz').outerHTML;
```

This will copy your quiz-form. then if you want to change values (and i think that is what you want) you need to give all elements an ID and align the new values to the elements. Like:

```
document.getElementByID('questions').value = 'new value';
```

Does your three Answers in the Example have the same ID? IDs must be unique.